# Why did my Ubuntu OS fail to boot up

Tags: boot

My question is. Why did it suddenly not boot?  Is this something I should expect to happen from time to time?  Below is the background.

From a powered off computer, one day after a normal shutdown, it stayed at a blank screen with the Ubuntu logo at the bottom.  I am running version 20.04 for the desktop.  It has done this one time before. In the first instance, I simply re-installed the OS using a bootable usb drive.  I had recently installed it so I did not have much to loose and just chocked it up to me being new to linux.

So when it happened a second time, after I had more invested in documents and more app installs  I re-started and choose the recovery mode.  It then did some processes and I continued the recovery boot.  The system booted up with minimal services. I re-booted again and it booted normally.

Computer is a custom build but fairly basic.  Intel i5 9th gen, no graphics card (using integrated), 500 gig ssd, asus z390-p motherboard, 32 gigs ram.

Again, the question is: Why did it suddenly not boot?  Is this something I should expect to happen from time to time?

Data Requested by @heynnema

```
jbunke@J-Bunke-Enterprises:~$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           31Gi       5.5Gi        21Gi       820Mi       3.8Gi        24Gi
Swap:         979Mi          0B       979Mi

jbunke@J-Bunke-Enterprises:~$ sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 60

jbunke@J-Bunke-Enterprises:~$ sudo lshw -C memory
[sudo] password for jbunke: 
  *-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: 2808
       date: 05/27/2020
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 16MiB
       capabilities: pci apm upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 3f
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 32GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: [empty]
          physical id: 0
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM1
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2666 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: BL16G32C16U4B.M16FE
          vendor: CRUCIAL
          physical id: 1
          serial: E44E9AD5
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM2
          size: 16GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2666MHz (0.4ns)
     *-bank:2
          description: [empty]
          physical id: 2
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM1
     *-bank:3
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2666 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: BL16G32C16U4B.M16FE
          vendor: CRUCIAL
          physical id: 3
          serial: E44E9EE2
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM2
          size: 16GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2666MHz (0.4ns)
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 4a
       slot: L1 Cache
       size: 384KiB
       capacity: 384KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 4b
       slot: L2 Cache
       size: 1536KiB
       capacity: 1536KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 4c
       slot: L3 Cache
       size: 9MiB
       capacity: 9MiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
  *-memory UNCLAIMED
       description: RAM memory
       product: Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
       version: 10
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
       capabilities: pm cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:a1316000-a1317fff memory:a131c000-a131cfff
```

More data requested by @heynnema

```
jbunke@J-Bunke-Enterprises:~$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=FEDE-412A  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
jbunke@J-Bunke-Enterprises:~$ cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume 
cat: /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume: No such file or directory
jbunke@J-Bunke-Enterprises:~$ cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume
cat: /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume: No such file or directory
jbunke@J-Bunke-Enterprises:~$ sudo blkid
[sudo] password for jbunke: 
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1: UUID="7ffeabb5-c0a1-4ab5-b3c8-5222d5c0a600" TYPE="swap"
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root: UUID="661fbc14-52e0-49a9-9650-7c76eb668dd7" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="FEDE-412A" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="ccb025e7-c65f-42ab-a8d3-939facad99cc"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: UUID="rs9tDP-TTZ3-j6kO-lCqt-YDzE-q3yT-boj3bB" TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTUUID="209c89dc-9071-450c-a2ca-6d1e5d0e5f4a"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="PQSERVICE" UUID="00847BE3847BDA1C" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="691acec4-01"
/dev/sda2: LABEL="SYSTEM RESERVED" UUID="94C87C71C87C5388" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="691acec4-02"
/dev/sda3: LABEL="Gateway" UUID="06DC7E0FDC7DF8EF" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="691acec4-03"
/dev/loop8: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop9: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop10: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop11: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop12: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop13: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop14: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop15: TYPE="squashfs"
jbunke@J-Bunke-Enterprises:~$ grep "GRUB_" /etc/default/grub
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
jbunke@J-Bunke-Enterprises:~$
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115966/discussion-on-question-by-jeff-why-did-my-ubuntu-os-fail-to-boot-up).

Comment: @ThomasW I tried to move to chat but was not allowed. Said my reputation was not high enough.

Comment: as a moderator I have several tricks up my sleeve; including the ability to force it.  It's all in chat, continue your support discussion there at the link in my comment.  (And flag for moderator attention with a custom flag asking to move comments to chat in the future if you want us to do it for you)

Answer (score 1):

I have multiple displays and the boot problem was occurring when both displays were on when the system attempted to boot. The workaround I will use is to leave the secondary monitor off while booting. After the system boots and the secondary monitor is turned on, it works fine.

I'm not sure if it is supposed to boot with both monitors on but the workaround is fine with me and not worth trying to make it work with both monitors on.

Update - I've found that I need to have the video cable unplugged from the back pannel, otherwise it will not boot. It's not enough to just have the monitor turned off.  Now that workaround is not ideal and I'll look further into why the system will not boot with 2 monitors connected.